# How to use console input and convert it to a .txt file?

Tags: java, file

I was suggested this code to write information generated in java into a .txt file. There were no errors but no files were created. I am using Eclipse and Mac OS X Mavericks.
The code:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

public class Practice13 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double totalSum = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many numbers would you like in the text files?");
        double a = in.nextDouble();
        double b = a;
        System.out.println("How mnay files would you like us to to create?");
        int g1 = in.nextInt();
        g1++;
        System.out.println("Would you like the average of all the numbers and the sum of all the numbers added to the end of the file?");
        System.out.println("(0) No");
        System.out.println("(1) Yes");
        double q = in.nextDouble();
        Random random = new Random();
        while (g1 > 1);
        {
            try
            {
                g1--;
                String g = Integer.toString(g1);
                FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter("/Users/Lam/Documents/"+g+".txt");
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);
                double counter = 0;
                double totalCounter = 0;
                while (a > 0)
                    {
                    double j = random.nextInt(200000);
                    totalSum = totalSum + j;
                    out.print(j);
                    out.print(", ");
                    a--;
                    counter++;
                    if (counter == 500000)
                        {
                        totalCounter = totalCounter + counter;
                        System.out.println("We are still working and have generated " + totalCounter + "numbers.");
                        counter = 0;
                        }
                    }
                a=b;
                if (q<0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Wow, how did you screw that one up?");
                    System.out.println("We have saved your file without the average and sum.");
                }
                if (q>1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Wow, how did you screw that one up?");
                    System.out.println("We have saved your file without the average and sum.");
                }
                if (q==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("We have not saved your file without the average and sum.");
                }
                if (q==1)
                {
                    System.out.println("We have saved the average and sum to the file.");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("The sum of all the random numbers is: " + totalSum);
                    System.out.println("The average of all the random number is: " + totalSum/b);
                }
                System.out.println("The task has completed");

                totalSum = 0;
                out.close();
            }   catch (IOException e)
            {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please learn to use a debugger.

Comment: You simply want to pipe the `System.in` to a file?

Comment: @BoristheSpider u r right!!

Comment: Please try to provide a minimal example. Remove all unnecceray code e.g. all `System.out.println` calls. Maybe you find the error yourself by reducing the problem.

Comment: Also use more descriptive variable names than `a` and `g1`. It is difficult to figure out their purpose otherwise.